# Convert array to space-delimited string, while joining individual values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, delimiter

I have a multiple `select` box on my page. I can get the values of all the selected child `option`s in jQuery easily like this:

```
$("#select").val();
```

That gives me an array like this:

```
["Hello", "Test", "Multiple Words"]
```

Now, I want to convert this array into a space-delimited string, but *also* join the individual words in each value with a dash, so that I end up with this:

```
"Hello Test Multiple-Words"
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = $.map($("#select").val() || [], function (x) {
    return x.replace(/\s/g, '-');
}).join(' ');
```

Comment: What's the point of using a regular expression as opposed to `String.replace(" ", "-")`?

Comment: using a string as the first parameter of the `replace` function will replace only the first occurrence while using a regular expression with a global flag will replace all occurrences.

Comment: Odd - not the behavior I would've expected. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 4):

```
var values = $("#select").val();

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
    values[i] = values[i].replace(" ", "-");
}

var spaceDelimitedString = values.join(" ");
```

Comment: You could construct the string inside the same for loop, which also preserves the original value in the list.

Answer (score 1):

If `Multiple-Words` can be as `Multiple Words`, then you can simply use `.join` and get the final output as `"Hello Test Multiple Words"`.

If not, you can write a loop like below to get the result.

```
var myList = ["Hello", "Test", "Multiple Words"];
var result = '';
for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
   result += myList[i].replace(/\s/g, '-') + ' ';
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bmXk5/

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job for you.

```
function combineWords(arr) {
    var i, l;
    for(i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i].replace(' ', '-') ;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var vals = ["Hello", "Test", "Multiple Words"];
var result = $.map(vals, function(str){ return str.replace(/\s/g, '-') })
  .join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple one liner with [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var arr = ["Hello", "Test", "Multiple Words"];
arr.map(function(val) { return val.replace(' ', '-') }).join(' ');
```